# もらいましょう meaning in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I know that ましょう form changes the verb meaning into "Let's". As in 行きましょう 'Let's go' or あそびましょう 'Let's play'.

But もらう verb means that something good is done by another person in which we are grateful. Would it means something like "Let's make someone do something good to us" ?

For example: しずかさんにすてきな歌を歌ってもらいましょう。 What I catch is: 'Let's (make someone) sing a good song for Shizuka'. Is this correct?

Comment: "Let's receive a singing performance from Shizuka" "Let us be endowed by..."

Comment: It could be as you say (e.g. しずかさんに歌う). Or it could be しずかさんにもらう, e.g. "receive singing from Shizuka".

Comment: I see... So it can have both meaning. @macraf yes, I believe your translations is very fit for the context (as in karaoke/similar event).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Make" is kind of strong as a translation. てもらう generally suggests that you are *having* someone do something for you, for your benefit, with implied gratitude. Also, as user dainichi also pointed out, while it technically could mean having someone sing to Shizuka, in all likelihood the speaker is talking about having Shizuka do the singing. You should remember 〇〇に△△をしてもらう as "having ○ do △," and the added ましょう is only the "let's" that you picked up on.

Comment: Is it possible to change もらいましょう into もらえましょう ? and how will it affect the sentence meaning ?

Comment: @Alice28 It would be ungrammatical. What would the intended effect be in that situation? When making requests you can use てもらえる, but using a volitional ましょう on it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Alice28 If you mean "we can probably get Shizuka's favor of singing for us", it makes sense.